# Deployed chain-code (0.5.7) is incompatible with client (0.7.2)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am unable to use the skeleton Fabric Composer CLI or angular applications running against the locally installed HLF.  I receive this error message:

Deployed chain-code (0.5.7) is incompatible with client (0.7.2)
    at HFCUtil.queryChainCode.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/
composer-connector-hlf/lib/hfcconnection.js:265:27)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

I can run my chain code using CLI statements directly in terminal but not using the CLI skeleton app or the Angular skeleton application.

Comment: Thanks James - that fixed it.  I just blew away and reinstalled the HLF by using yo fabric-composer to regenerate the CLI application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyway to update the version of the chain-code you have deployed, so I think you'll need clean up and redeploy.